# How can I improve order().by() performance in Neptune?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to solve a performance issue with a traversal and have tracked it down to the `order().by()` step. It seems that `order().by()` greatly increases the number of statement index ops required (per the profiler) and dramatically slows down execution.

A non-ordered traversal is very fast:

```
g.V().hasLabel("post").limit(40)
```

execution time: 2 ms

index ops: 1

Adding a single ordering step adds thousands of index ops and runs much slower.

```
g.V().hasLabel("post").order().by("createdDate", desc).limit(40)
```

execution time: 62 ms

index ops: 3909

Adding a single filtering step adds thousands more index ops and runs even slower:

```
g.V().hasLabel("post").has("isActive", true).order().by("createdDate", desc).limit(40)
```

execution time: 113 ms

index ops: 7575

However the same filtered traversal without ordering runs just as fast as the original unfiltered traversal:

```
g.V().hasLabel("post").has("isActive", true).limit(40)
```

execution time: 1 ms

index ops: 49

By the time we build out the actual traversal we run in production there are around 12 filtering steps and 4 `by()` step-modulators causing the traversal to take over 6000 ms to complete with over 33000 index ops. Removing the `order().by()` steps causes the same traversal to run fast (500 ms).

The issue seems to be with `order().by()` and the number of index ops required to sort. I have seen the performance issue noted [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-traversal-tuning.html) but adding `barrier()` did not help. The traversal is also fully optimized requiring no Tinkerpop conversion.

I am running engine version 1.1.0.0 R1. There are about 5000 `post` vertices.

How can I improve the performance of this traversal?

Answer (score 0):

So generally the only way you are going to increase the performance of ordering in any graph database (including Neptune) is to filter items down to a minimal set prior to performing the ordering.

An `order().by()` step requires that all elements that match the criteria must be returned for them to be ordered as specified.  When using only a `limit(N)` step then as soon as `N` items are returned the traversal terminates.  This is why you are seeing significantly faster times for the `limit()` only option, it just has to process and return less data since it is returning the first `N` records which may be in any order.